# Gupshup Flow Bot

Tags: bots, viber, gupshup

Gupshup integrated bot on **Viber** not working. May be it is because I am using russian language? There is not a Welcome Message or a start button here. And when user trying to write something then bot sends one message only and this is my message about error or unknown commands. I have tried to Deploy and it doesn't help me. What is wrong?

P.S. Trying to edit the bot, but can not doing it because website freezes on

> "Trying to resurrect IDE Server... Please Wait!"

Comment: To publish on Viber you need the public account. Do you have the public account approved by Viber? Also, you are using the Flow Bot Builder, correct? can you provide your bot name on Gupshup so that we can take a look? Also, I created a bot with Russian language and tested it using the Gupshup proxy bot on Viber. You can give it a try. Go to http://www.viber.com/gupshupproxybot follow this Public Account. Then start a p2p chat then type in "Proxy russianbot". Also, look at this demo https://youtu.be/wCBDREm03dM to know more.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I have a Viber public account ! I`m using your Flow Bot Builder correctly. I am trying delete and create new bots. And they all work once, before I change standart bot text. When I added own text, video and carusel menu it not working for me in my phone Viber app but it works where I tested on Gupshup. Name of my bot on Gupshup - ViberCoaching or trying in Viber: viber://public?id=coachingbots

Comment: When I tested it in Messenger that get message "video posting failed" Why failed video? I`m using youtube link for video adding.

Comment: And when I add Telegram Channel the bot not shown Video and Carousel! The bot show link only but in Gupshup it works as test and works in Gupshup Proxy Bot.

Comment: Every platform has it's own limitations. Facebook will only show video from a link with mp4. Like this www.abc.com/funvideo/mp4 . YouTube video will not work. Also the video should be 90 seconds long at max. Viber again as limitations to the number of elements in the carousel etc.  This document should help https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/viber-carousel.Similarly, Telegram has it's own limitations like it doesn't support carousel but it supports the button with text. Hence I would recommend reading about platform features first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a different browser. It works for me.